# Getting stuck with the clientside validation in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation, devexpress, client-side

I have the following problem:
  In my application I have two textboxes in a aspxCallbackPanel

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtCognome" runat="server" Width="270px" ReadOnly="True">
   <ValidationSettings CausesValidation="True" ErrorText="Cognome can't be blank" 
        SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="group1">
        <RequiredField IsRequired="True" />
   </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>

<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtNome" ClientInstanceName="nome" runat="server" Width="270px" ReadOnly="True">
    <ValidationSettings CausesValidation="True" SetFocusOnError="True" 
         ValidationGroup="group1">
         <RequiredField IsRequired="True" />
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

As far as you see I have added only a RequiredFieldValidation. However on a specific moment before I do a postback I want to see if the page is valid:

```
 var validated = Page_ClientValidate('group1');
    if (validated){
        DoPostBack('Save'); 
    } else {
        return alert('mamata si e ebalo');
    }
```

However nothing happens. When I try to alert validated, nothing appears ... Any ideas why and is this the right way to do a client side validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup('group1')){
    DoPostBack('Save'); 
} else {
    return alert('oops');
}
```

is the right approach to my problem

Answer (score 0):

In javascript we use return false to stop postback like this

```
var validated = Page_ClientValidate('group1');
if (validated){
    DoPostBack('Save'); 
} else {
    return alert('mamata si e ebalo');
    return false;
}
```

Edit:

Wrap this into a function like this

```
function validate() //javascript function
{
  if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') 
  {
    var validated = Page_ClientValidate('group1');
    if (validated){
    DoPostBack('Save'); 
    } else {
    return alert('mamata si e ebalo');
    return false;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: cool but my problem is that the program doesn't get into the if .. so there is something wrong with the validated

Comment: Hmmm still the same problem ... maybe there is a problem with the validation settings of the textboxes